Crime thriller with a man wrongfully accused of a crime he staged
The movie I am trying to find is one I saw some of many years ago and it was an old film then probably a 1960s film if not earlier.
From what I can remember a guy stages a crime with the help of his friend  (think it may have been a murder) so that it looks as if he done the crime and he will be convicted and sent to jail (possibly the death penalty). His friend is the only person who has the evidence that will exonerate him and as his friend is about to go to the court to present the evidence he is killed in a car accident which causes a fire and the evidence is destroyed in the fire....
It was a brilliant story but I have never seen it all or seen it again or met anyone whom could identify the film. I recall some details from the movie where they took photos of them falsely planting evidence and when the friend was killed in the car crash he was reversing out of a drive onto a highway. Cant remember if it was an American movie or British but one or the other like a kind of Hitchcock type movie.

Was thinking it was Dial M for Murder but the details dont match up. Im sure ive seen this movie though

Yeah seen Dial M for Murder a couple of times... great film but definitely not this movie.

You're looking for Fritz Lang's Beyond A Reasonable Doubt from 1956.

Austin Spencer (Sidney Blackmer), a newspaper publisher, wants to prove a point about the inadequacy of circumstantial evidence. He talks his son-in-law, Tom Garrett (Dana Andrews), into participating in a hoax, in an attempt to expose the ineptitude of the city's hard-line district attorney. The plan is for Tom to plant clues which will lead to his arrest for the murder of a female nightclub dancer, Patty Gray. Once Tom is found guilty, Spencer is to reveal the setup and humiliate the District Attorney.
Tom agrees to the plan, not knowing that unforeseen events will put a snag in the scheme. Spencer dies in a car accident before he can testify, and photographic evidence intended to clear Tom at his trial is burned to an unrecognizable state. Tom is found guilty and placed on death row in prison.

The accident is exactly as you've described (a truck hits him when he comes out of the garage). Here's the trailer:




Thank you very much Walt for solving the mystery i have been trying to solve for many years... awesome!!
